# Run Windows and Ubuntu simultaneously?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Theoretically possible to run two operating systems simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/288554/theoretically-possible-to-run-two-operating-systems-simultaneously)

I currently run Windows 7 in VirtualBox with full DirectX and Direct3D support but without support for graphics card integration, it's not as good as actually running the operating system.

Is there any way to boot into both (or more) operating systems at the same time, hibernating (or sleeping) when switching to another? Logging off of one just to play games or use iTunes on Windows is a waste of time, but if there is no other way I will have to make due.

Tech Specs:

```
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965 3.4GHz
GPU: HIS Radeon HD 5850 (Cypress Pro) 1GB 256-bit
RAM: 16GB (4 x 4GB) DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800)
```

Comment: To me this sounds impossible - when you switched to another OS, the initals OS's RAM would be wiped (program data, etc, lost), the CPU would be emptied, and a variety of other things. It would make sense to me (But this further complicates the problem) to have a THIRD OS (or something( that can handle this task of switching between operating systems / ram / processor usage. But that is just a theory.

Comment: Why not use Windows as the host?

Comment: I think it is impossible but good question . 
@iglvx why you want to change the question ?!!!

Comment: Check this out (I got it from a comment on the link kobaltz gave) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor